# Django Admin custom view using get_urls - doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

I have followed the django docs and I'have added the following code to my models admin.py file

My model is CustomerOrder and my app name is customer_orders

```
class CustomerOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(CustomerOrderAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^upload/$', self.upload)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def upload(self, request):
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        pass
```

Now when i try to visit '**/admin/customer_orders/customerorder/upload/**' as mentioned in the django docs it fails with the following error.

**object with primary key u'upload' does not exist.**

And the error seems obvious as **'/admin/customer_orders/customerorder/pk_id'** takes me to the particular model data with the given primary key.

I don't know what I've missed.

Comment: Are you sure you have registered the CustomerOrderAdmin class as the modeladmin for the relevant model?

Comment: I just want to leave here that your view doesn't use any of the usual admin security measures (requiring admin login etc.) unless you explicitly add it. The easiest way is probably to use `self.admin_site.admin_view(self.upload)` as the view in your `url()` function.